# Concatenate multiple arrays in a array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this multiple array:

```
var array = [["par0_0","par0_1","par0_2"],["par1_0","par1_1","par1_2"],["par2_0","par2_1","par2_2"]];
```

I would like to transform this array in the following array of strings:

```
var result = [["par0_0,par1_0,par2_0"],["par0_1,par1_1,par2_1"],["par0_2,par1_2,par2_2"]];
```

What is the most efficient way?

Comment: Is the first array an array of strings? are you missing double quotes?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Question edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toString()` on `array` to convert the array **values** to string and concat them.

```js
var myArr = [
  ['par0_0', 'par0_1', 'par0_2'],
  ['par1_0', 'par1_1', 'par1_2'],
  ['par2_0', 'par2_1', 'par2_2']
];

var myArrLen = myArr.length,
  myOutput = []; // The output array

for (var i = 0; i < myArrLen; i++) {
  var arrEl = []; // Initialize the array for inserting sub-array
  for (var j = 0; j < myArr[i].length; j++) {
    arrEl.push(myArr[j][i]); // Add items from same column into sub-array
  }

  myOutput[i] = [arrEl.toString()]; // Assign the string to output array
}
document.write(myOutput);
console.log(myOutput);
```

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mnbx61am/)

Comment: @JosepBacardit What do you mean by that? Can you please create `jsfiddle` of the same

Comment: In the first array of the result, I want to add the first value of all arrays. In the second array result I want to add the second value of all arrays. Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/drzkzaxL/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`reduce()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) twice

```
[par0_0, par0_1, par0_2].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
   var result = "";
   if (index != 0)
   {
      result = ",";
   }
   return result + previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join()`. Here is an example:

```
var arr = [["par0_0","par0_1","par0_2"],
["par1_0","par1_1","par1_2"],
["par2_0","par2_1","par2_2"]]

for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = [arr[i].join()] ;
}
```

`join()` accepts an optional separator argument if you do not want to commas. Default separator is comma.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join